# Merging mobile version into desktop one

Tags: c#, mobile, unity-game-engine, merge, desktop

Me and a couple of friends made a game, and decided to do a different project for its Mobile version. After a couple of updates, we understood that it takes some time to push them for both, and we want to merge both into one project, which works for both Desktop and Mobile.

Is it possible to copy one of the project into the others with its meta files? Because when i tried that, our Mobile version's scene objects import the Desktop scripts, rather than its own Mobile scripts?

Comment: unfortunately no, it's really not possible in any way.  you just have to manually make a new project.

Comment: @JoeBlow I believe that you can generate pc/mobile/console releases from the same project using unity. All you have to do is select the build mode. However, your answer is correct; it is impossible importing the metafiles.

Comment: Hi Cab!  Right, of course you generate them all from the same project.  The OP should have started with one project to begin with.  The meta files as such as totally irrelevant - you can and should throw away the whole Libraty/ folder at any time. IT's just tha there;'s no automatic way to "combine two projects" - - - in practice they'd have to start fresh with a new project....